# Numpy: Diff on non-adjacent values

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to take the difference of non-adjacent values within a 1D numpy array.

The array is a selection of values along a timeline from 1 to `N`.

For `N=12`, the array could look like

```
timeline = np.array([ 0, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 6, np.nan, np.nan, 9, np.nan, 11, 12])
```

or like

```
timeline = np.array([ 0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  6,  0,  0,  9,  0, 11, 12])
```

The desired result should look like: (size of array is intact and position is important)

```
diff = np.array([ 0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  2,  0,  0,  3,  0, 2, 1])
```

`np.diff` returns the difference of adjacent values, and utilising NaN values to "force" it to use last "good" value, does not work.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You'll need masks

Comment: So the first value always stays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lists of indices. I'm assuming you want to keep the first value as-is.

For zero spacers:

```
imask = np.flatnonzero(timeline)
diff = np.zeros_like(timeline)
diff[imask[0]] = timeline[imask[0]]
diff[imask[1:]] = timeline[imask[1:]] - timeline[imask[:-1]]
```

Or more elegantly, replace the last two lines with:

```
diff[imask] = np.diff(timeline[imask], prepend=0)
```

For `nan`s just replace the first line with

```
imask = np.flatnonzero(~np.isnan(timeline))
```

If you have access to the original mask used to make the selection, all the better. Use it as the argument to `flatnonzero` instead.

Comment: IIUC, you can replace lines 3 and 4 with `diff[imask] = np.diff(timeline[imask], prepend=timeline[0])` to avoid creating all the views

Comment: Looks more elegant by far, but the prepend makes a copy of the masked data.

Comment: @user3483203. Updated

Comment: Hmm, definitely seems like there is a more efficient way for prepend to be implemented here than a copy, I didn't realize that was the case.  It would definitely slow things down for large inputs.